# Weird result of initiating a variable with the output of 'git describe'

Tags: bash, git, stdout

For some reason this assignment: `OUT=$(git describe HEAD)` prints to the stdout (for example): `fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.`

Is this a normal behavior? Why doesn't this happen with other commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually `stderr` output, not `stdout`. When running a command from an interactive terminal, both `stdout` and `stderr` are set to go to the terminal.

If you wanted the `stderr` output in your variable (which you probably don't, but anyway), redirect it to `stdout` like this:

```
OUT=$(git describe HEAD 2>&1)
```

Or if you didn't want the person running your script to see that `stderr` output, throw it away like this:

```
OUT=$(git describe HEAD 2>/dev/null)
```